# How can I dinamically change list_view columns based on a filter in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How (if even possible) can I change the order of the columns in the `list_display` in Django admin UI based on a filter?

For example, if not filter is applied, the admin list of a model shows columns `A, B, C, D, E`. If a specific filter is selected, then the columns displayed would change to `B, C, E, A, D`.

If this is possible, how can I do it? Can I change the name of the columns to use custom columns device in my `ModelAdmin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is possible using `get_list_display()` method of the model admin.

```py
def get_list_display(self, request):
   filter_value = request.GET.get('foo', False) # False is the default value if the key is not found
   if filter_value and filter_value == 'foo':
       list_display = (B, C, E, A, D)
   else:
       list_display = (A, B, C, D, E)
```